# Sitecore Publishable flag makes it impossible to GetItem() from Master database

Tags: sitecore

I'm using sitecore 6.6.0 (rev. 120918). From the sitecore admin portal, I go and turn off the **Publishable** flag of an item (see image).

[image]

After this, `Sitecore.Data.Database.GetDatabase("master").GetItem("{itemID}")` returns **null**.

If I turn ON the Publishable flag again, `GetItem()` returns the correct item. What's the reason for this behaviour? **Publishable** setting controls the ability to publish to the Web database. Why does it effect the `GetItem()` API call to the master database?

Comment: Works on my machine :) Did exactly what you did and it returns the item...

Comment: Are you running in "Live" mode?

Comment: Thanks for trying it out guys! No I'm not using Live mode. We use the web database to view published content on the public site. But in some special scenarios we directly access the master database to get some items.

Answer (score 11):

I've found a way around this for cases where you *really* need to read from the `ContentDatabase` (i.e. master database) and don't want items to publish. This could be user generated content, for example. In Active Commerce, we run into this with content such as Wish Lists which are always read from master in preview or non-staged environments, and are accessed via web service in staged environments.

By setting `Sitecore.Context.Site.DisableFiltering` to `true`, the filtering of unpublishable items will be disabled. I've implemented a simple `IDisposable` that allows you to temporarily disable filtering, with an optional condition.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ActiveCommerce.SitecoreX
{
    public class ItemFilteringDisabler : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly bool _disableCondition = true;

        public ItemFilteringDisabler()
        {
            Sitecore.Context.Site.DisableFiltering = true;
        }

        public ItemFilteringDisabler(bool disableCondition)
        {
            _disableCondition = disableCondition;
            if (_disableCondition)
            {
                Sitecore.Context.Site.DisableFiltering = true;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_disableCondition)
            {
                Sitecore.Context.Site.DisableFiltering = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example use:

```
using (new ItemFilteringDisabler(!Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsNormal))
{
    Sitecore.Data.Database.GetDatabase("master").GetItem("{itemID}");
}
```

Comment: ItemFilteringDisabler Solved my problem !

Answer (score 2):

I have now found that the reason is the sitecore preview feature. In my previous checks with `GetItem()` I happen to have used the preview feature earlier as a sitecore admin. After that my whole public site goes into preview mode (bit annoying) therefore the item ceases to be accessible (even via the master database API call).

From what I have discovered these are the rules:

- If the item is NOT publishable and if the website is in preview mode,
  `Sitecore.Data.Database.GetDatabase("master").GetItem("{itemID}")`
  returns null.
- The unpublishable item also cannot be previewed. Sitecore doesn't even seem to load the sublayout for the item.

I'm going to ask in a separate question on why the preview feature places such restrictions on items which are not publishable.

Comment: That is so it can show a proper preview. In preview mode it is still working off the master database, but it is showing the user what the site would look like on delivery - previewing it - that's why there is a date control, you can set something publishable in the future and change the preview date to make sure that it becomes visible on the correct dates etc... A preview that didn't take into account publish restrictions would not be very helpful :)

Comment: Thanks Richard. That's meaningful. Unfortunately doesn't help our cause. :-)